# ¿como puedo decirle a firebase realtime database que el dato que quiero almacenar es de tipo numerico?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, realtime-database

estoy tratando de almacenar una valor desde un formulario con html y javascript en firebase realtime database.
el valor almacenado en realtime database debe ser guardado en numerico y siempre me lo guarda como cadena de texto, ya probe con entrada numerica en el formulario, convirtiendo el valor obtenido del form a numerico o asignarlo a una variable numerica pero a la hora de hacer set siempre me lo almacena como cadena string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mí me funcionó esto usando firestore

```
const guardar = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault()
await addDoc( productosCollection, { descripcion: descripcion, 
stock:parseInt(stock) })
navigate('/')
}
```

En este caso quise guardar stock como entero, lo único que hice fue parsearlo y efectivamente se me guarda en firestore como number, sé que estás usando otro servicio de firebase pero según esto https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9T4UnpOTMhY también funciona en la realtime database

Espero que te ayude